# Matrix multiplication of arbitrary sizes

Tags: java, mathematics, matrix

This function is for multiplying two matrices together. It's kind of messed up because the result is actually supposed to overwrite the object that called it, or since it's `static`, it's supposed to overwrite the `left` object. Is there any way to make it faster or more readable?

```
public static Matrix multiply(Matrix left, Matrix right){
    int leftRows = left.numRows;
    int leftColumns = left.numCols;
    int rightRows = right.numRows;
    int rightColumns = right.numCols;
    if (leftColumns != rightRows)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dimensions don't match");

    Double[][] result = new Double[leftRows][rightColumns];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 && i < leftRows; i++) {//I found the && i <leftRows to be necessary for handling matrices of 1 row
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 && j < rightColumns; j++) {//&& j <rightColumns necessary for matrices with 1 columns
            result[i][j] = 0.00000;//ensures no null reference
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < leftRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rightColumns; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < leftColumns; k++)
            {
                if(result[i][j] == null)
                    result[i][j] = 0.0;
                result[i][j] += left.getValue(i, k) * right.getValue(k, j);
            }
        }
    }

    Matrix product = new Matrix(leftRows, rightColumns);
    for(int i = 0; i < leftRows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < rightColumns; j++)
            Matrix.setValueAt(product, i, j, result[i][j]);
    }
    return product;     

 }
```

Comment: Is this code doing what it is supposed to be? It doesn't sound like it is..... in which case you should take this to [so], not here on CodeReview. See the [help/on-topic] for guidance.

Comment: when you do get it working we would be happy to review the **working** code.

Answer (score 3):

My question would be: Why is it supposed to "overwrite" the left value? This seems dubious from a software engineering point of view. The product of two matrices is: A<sub>nm</sub> x B<sub>mp</sub> = C<sub>np</sub> hence you can only "overwrite" A with C (re-using the same Matrix object) if `m == p` or in other words if B is a quadratic matrix.

For now let's clean up the existing code by getting rid of the intermediate array

```
public static Matrix multiply(Matrix left, Matrix right) {
    int leftRows = left.numRows;
    int leftColumns = left.numCols;
    int rightRows = right.numRows;
    int rightColumns = right.numCols;

    if (leftColumns != rightRows)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dimensions don't match");

    Matrix product = new Matrix(leftRows, rightColumns);
    for (int i = 0; i < leftRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rightColumns; j++)
        {
            double cellValue = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < leftColumns; k++)
            {
                cellValue += left.getValue(i, k) * right.getValue(k, j);
            }
            Matrix.setValueAt(product, i, j, cellValue);
        }
    }

    return product;
 }
```

You could copy the values back into `left` - provided `right` is quadratic and therefore `product` and `left` will have the same dimensions. Otherwise if the `Matrix` class offers a re-sizing option then you could re-size left afterwards and copy `product` into it. However that is extremely ugly and I would question that requirement.

As a side note: It seems weird that `Matrix` provides a static method for setting a cell value of a `Matrix` object. I would have expected that to be an instance method as well like `getValue()`.

Answer (score -1):

For improving readability, you could perhaps replace the for-loop variable names with more descriptive names, such as 'currentColumn' and 'currentRow.'

For performance, you can replace 'x++' with '++x' in every loop. 'x++' actually creates a copy of x, increments x, and returns the copy. It is useful in some situations, but unnecessary in a for-loop.

Now I'll admit that I don't work in Java, and Matrixes are a haze from school, but it seems like 'result' could just be set to a Matrix from the start, instead of a
double[][]. You would cut down a significant portion of your time spent copying from 'result' to 'product' by just using a Matrix in the first place.

I don't see the need for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2 && i < leftRows; i++) {//I found the && i <leftRows to be necessary for handling matrices of 1 row
    for (int j = 0; j < 2 && j < rightColumns; j++) {//&& j <rightColumns necessary for matrices with 1 columns
        result[i][j] = 0.00000;//ensures no null reference
    }
```

Please explain where a null reference might arise without this code.

Comment: The compiler should be able to should be able to know that the result of `x++` is not used and optimize it. Even if it doesn't, I wouldn't make the change unless a profiler said it was a bottle neck. `result` is an array of `Double`, not the primitive `double`, so the array is initialized with `null`s. I agree that the values should be written directly to `product` instead of copying them from `result`.

Comment: changing the names of the vars won't help, since the vars are used as column and row indexes in different places. ++x and x++ makes no difference in performance in Java (that can be measured). The array needs to be set non-null because it is an array of `Double`, not `double`.

Comment: The doubles are initialised to null, but won't they all be overwritten? I didn't realise x++ was optimised out, I typically use ++x wherever possible as per [link](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Preincrement_and_Predecrement). Just a preference.

Comment: Also, only one downvote on my first answer on Stack Exchange - I think that's not too bad.

Comment: @rolfl Within each for-loop, would it not be more clear using 'currentRow' and 'currentCollumn' than 'i' and 'j'? Using the right index variable in each matrix is a lot easier with more descriptive names.

Comment: @Andrew Just keep answering and you'll get plenty of up-votes soon enough :)

Comment: @Andrew In, for example, `cellValue += left.getValue(i, k) * right.getValue(k, j);` would you make the `k` the row, or the column?

Comment: I see. My first instinct would be to set I and k to the values of the left matrix, but you're right - this would probably make it harder, not easier, to read. I'll go hide in my corner now.